# Iterate through two objects sequences in Scala and return true if a condition is fulfilled

Tags: scala, sequence

I have two sequences of objects Seq[A] and Seq[B]. Seq[A] is a list of objects, that have this form

```scala
case class A(type: String,
             label: String,
             code: String)
```

And Seq[B] is a list of rules that tells me a pair (key, regex)

```scala
case class B(key: String,
             regex: String)
```

I need to check if a element in the first list its `type` match one of the keys on the second list then the `code` has to match the corespondent `regex`

Comment: Do you want all the matches? Just the first one? Do you care about the matched value or just know if there is a match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by using a combination of `filter`, `map`, and `exists` functions provided by the Scala collections API. Here's a method that checks the described criteria:

```scala
case class A(typ: String, label: String, code: String)
case class B(key: String, regex: String)

def checkRules(as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B]): Seq[A] = {
  as.filter(a => 
    bs.exists(b => 
      a.typ == b.key && a.code.matches(b.regex)
    )
  )
}

val listOfA: Seq[A] = Seq(
  A("type1", "label1", "code1"),
  A("type2", "label2", "code1234"),
  // ... other elements
)

val listOfB: Seq[B] = Seq(
  B("type1", "^code[0-9]$"),
  B("type2", "^code[0-9]{4}$"),
  // ... other rules
)

val matchingAs = checkRules(listOfA, listOfB)
println(matchingAs) // This will print the sublist from A that satisfy the conditions
```

Answer (score 4):

Turning the `B` sequence into a `Map` beforehand may be wise if the number of elements in it is significant. Also, since you are asking to just return `true` if a condition is true, it makes sense to use `exists` outside rather than `filter`, so you stop as soon as you find a match:

```
   val bMap = bSeq.map(b => b.key -> b.regex).toMap
   aSeq.exists { a => bMap.get(a.type).exists(r => a.code.matches(r)) }
```

Comment: Actually I need to return true only if all the elements `Seq[A]` so I used the solution given by @miloserdow and check if the new list is equal to the original. I see that in my post that is not very clear, but your answer is very good to

Comment: For all elements, there is `.forall` ...