# Check if some elements in a Scala's object sequence exist in other list and fulfill condition

Tags: scala, sequence

I have two sequences of objects `Seq[A]` and `Seq[B]`. `Seq[A]` is a list of objects, that have this form

```scala
case class A (tipo: String,
              label: String,
              code: String)
```

And the B type is like this

```scala
case class B (key: String,
              valid_types: Seq[String],
              isOptional: Boolean)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76870705/iterate-through-two-objects-sequences-in-scala-and-return-true-if-a-condition-is) is similar and already help me with the non optional elements on `Seq[B]` like this:

```scala
def validation (listA: Seq[A], listB: Seq[B]): Boolean = {
    listB.filter(b => !b.isOptional)
        .forall { config =>
        listA.exists {a =>
            a.code == config.key && config.valid_types.contains(a.tipo)
        }
    }
}
```

that code let me check that all the non optional **keys** in `Seq[B]` are some element's **code** in `Seq[A]` and those element have a valid type

But for my current problem I need to do that now need to only need to do it for optional elements that may or may not be in `Seq[A]`

```scala
def validateOptional (listA: Seq[A], listB: Seq[B]): Boolean = {
    listB.filter(b => b.isOptional)
        .exists(config => listA.exists(a => a.code == b.key))
}
```

this code returns true if some of the optional **key** in `Seq[B]` is a element's **code** in `Seq[A]`
I need to check if some of the elements in `Seq[A]` its **key** matches the **code** of an **optional** element in `Seq[B]` then check if the **tipo** of that element in `Seq[A]` is exist in the **valid_types** on the other elements
Finally return true if all elements that fulfill the first condition also fulfill second one
If in `Seq[A]` are no optional elements also return true
But I really can figure out how to do that second check

Comment: So... you are telling us that... you have a variable names `type`... and your code compiles ?

Comment: I have a hard time trying to understand what you are trying to do. Please add some punctuation marks and maybe insert another paragraph to separate the description of your task from the things you tried.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @sarveshseri, in fact the name of the variable is **tipo** (type in spanish), but in my eagerness to translate, I didn't notice it